# Length of the longest subsequence in a list of integers

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I want to get good at functional programming so I set myself some tasks.

I want to determine the **length** of the longest subsequence in a list of integers, where the **next element** is **incremented by 1**.

So the result should be

```
incsubseq [] ~?= 0,
incsubseq [5] ~?= 1,
incsubseq [1,2,3,5,6] ~?= 3,
incsubseq [5,6,1,2,3] ~?= 3,
incsubseq [5,6,1,4,3] ~?= 2,
incsubseq [6,5,4,3,2,1] ~?= 1]
```

My try was this:

```
incsubseq :: [Int] -> Int
incsubseq [] = 0
incsubseq [_] = 1
incsubseq (a:b)
          | a == ((head b)-1) = 1 + (incsubseq b)
          | a /= ((head b)-1) = (incsubseq b)
```

But of course this only works for lists that don't have a longer subsequence e.g. [**1,2,3**,42] = **3**, but not for lists like [1,2,**100,101,102**] which should  be 3 but is **NOT** (It's 2)!

I would really, really appreciate your help since this problem drives me crazy, coming from OO- Programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this using a technique called *accumulators*: you call a function together with certain values that are modified along the run. The base-case then returns the result of a function calculated with these *accumulators*.

For this specific problem we introduce two accumulators: `curi` and `maxi`. `curi` stores the length of the current sequence, and `maxi` contains the thus far seen maximum incrementing sequence.

The base case is when we reach the end of the list in which case we return the `maxi`:

```
maxincsub [] curi maxi = maxi
```

Another base case is when we encounter the very last element. In that case we return the maximum of `maxi` and `curi`:

```
maxincsub [_] curi maxi = max curi maxi
```

The inductive case is when we see two elements in the list: we determine whether `a1` is an increment of `a2`. If so, we increment `curi`. If not, we set `curi` back to `1`, but first set `maxi` to the maximum of `maxi` this far and `curi`:

```
maxincsub (a0:a1:as) curi maxi | a0+1 == a1 = maxincsub (a1:as) (curi+1) maxi
                               | otherwise = maxincsub (a1:as) 1 (max curi maxi)
```

or putting it all together:

```
maxincsub [] curi maxi = maxi
maxincsub [_] curi maxi = max curi maxi
maxincsub (a0:a1:as) curi maxi | a0+1 == a1 = maxincsub (a1:as) (curi+1) maxi
                               | otherwise = maxincsub (a1:as) 1 (max curi maxi)
```

Finally we need to bind your function `incsubseq` with our `maxincsub` by setting initial values for `curi` and `maxi`:

```
incsubseq :: [Int] -> Int
incsubseq xs = maxincsub xs 1 0
```

Tetsting this with your given input gives:

```
*Main> incsubseq []
0
*Main> incsubseq [5]
1
*Main> incsubseq [1,2,3,4,5,6]
6
*Main> incsubseq [1,2,3,5,6]
3
*Main> incsubseq [5,6,1,2,3]
3
*Main> incsubseq [5,6,1,4,3]
2
*Main> incsubseq [6,5,4,3,2,1]
1
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

You are solving too many problems at the same time - I would try to break the problem down in more understandable steps

1. create all sequences in the list
2. create a new list with their `length`s using `map`
3. find the `maximum` of the lengths

Now the first part would be easy if your sequences were "all the same things" then `group` from `Data.List` would be sufficient, but here this is not the case, and unfortunately `groupBy (\x y -> x + 1 == y)` which would be exactly what you are looking for - does not work (for technical reasons I do not want to expand).

So first of all you need to implement your own `groupBy'` function or "cheat" and look [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_function_suggestions#Generalize_groupBy_and_friends) where I got

> ```
> groupBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
> groupBy rel []          =  []
> groupBy rel (x:xs)      =  (x:ys) : groupBy rel zs
>    where (ys,zs) = groupByAux x xs
>          groupByAux x0 (x:xs) | rel x0 x = (x:ys, zs)
>            where (ys,zs) = groupByAux x xs
>          groupByAux y xs = ([], xs)
> ```

then you can simply `groupBy (\x y -> x + 1 == y) [1,2,100,101,102]`

Then the next steps should be manageable.

Note: if you want the longest sequence you can make a shortcut and use `` maximumBy (compare `on` length) ``.

Full solution:

> ```
> import Data.Function (on)
> import Data.List (maximum)
>
> longestLength :: [Int] -> Int
> longestLength xx = maximum $ map length $ groupBy' (\x y -> x + 1 == y) xx
>
> groupBy = ... -- see above
> ```

Comment: Thank you as well!